# gql query returns BadQueryError: Parse Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

This is my gql code:

```
data = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Playlist " + "WHERE tags = :1" + "ORDER BY :2", tag, order)
```

and I get this error:

BadQueryError: Parse Error: Expected no additional symbols at symbol BY

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

thanks for the help
J

Comment: Why on earth are you contatenating multiple string constants together like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be concatenating the GQL string for some unknown reason and have missed a space. Try:

```
data = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Playlist WHERE tags = :1 ORDER BY :2", tag, order)
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a space before `ORDER`.